# Hide class CSS for specific user role Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

I need to hide the class ".price-rules-table-wrapper" from all users and visitors, with the exception of "Revenda" users.

it's possible?

Comment: Hi could you please share some of your code . what you have done. so it might be helpful.

Comment: When posting a question, please be specific and/or provide an example of your code. (as @TanmoySarkar pointed out).

In general, if you want to remove a certain class from the body tag, you can have a look at the `body_class` filter hook ([see WordPress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/)). Inside a function added to this hook, you can check if a certain user is logged in or not and remove the class from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in `PHP` we can use something like this

Moreover you can find [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.php)

```
session_start();
 if($_SESSION['userlvl'] === "Revenda") {
    $userlvlpermission = '<div class="price-rules-table-wrapper">hiii</div>';
    }
 //At where you wanted to place the "price-rules-table-wrapper"
 <?php if($userlvlpermission){echo $userlvlpermission;}?>
```

Comment: add this "USER" in header this my website: [link](https://jlimaimportadores.pt/)

Comment: but not hide :(

Comment: I have updated my code. you can just remove `USER`. and check with this.

Comment: No you can use it where you want to display  this div.

Comment: As this is your header so probably it should be in your index.php.

check this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: are you able to to see `var_dump[$session]` ?

Comment: i dont understand this php... i add this code in my index.php, and visit website, but class show for me :(